# Postgis create polygon extent/convex hull from spatial table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, extents, convex-hull

Please help,

I have a polygon layer representing building footprints. I want to create new view in postgis that will contain rectangle representing bounding box and also another view that will have convex hulls polygon of all records in buildings table.
I'm creating something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW xxx.extent AS SELECT ST_ConvexHull(buildings_2013.geom) as geom from xxx.buildings_2013;
```

but I won't create spatial view. Could you please help?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Is your schema actually called xxx?

Comment: Schema is called xxx. I got no error, that  statement is creating view but it is ordinary table,no spatial one.

Comment: What is it the output exactly?

Comment: Output is simple table. Problem was it was geometry table but qGIS didn't see that geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by no spatial view.  You mean you are not seeing it in geometry_columns table or your viewer is not loading it?  If you are using PostGIS 1.5 or lower, you have to manually add the view to the table geometry_columns table.  In PostGIS 2.0+, it will show in list but won't show type.  To get type you need to do cast it.

Also many views like QGIS for example are finicky and won't load something if it has no id it recognizes as a key.  You can try throwing in the primary key like gid or something in the view.  So PostGIS 2+ definition should look
Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW xxx.extent AS 
  SELECT gid, ST_ConvexHull(buildings_2013.geom)::geometry(POLYGON,4326) As geom 
   FROM xxx.buildings_2013;
```

replace 4326 with the SRID of your geom column.  It has to be a constant for casting unfortunately so you can't just do geometry(POLYGON, ST_SRID(geom).

Comment: By spatial view I meant viewing it in qGIS like a shapefile. I saw geometry column but qGIS were not able to load it. No it's working just fine! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: One more thing, your statement creating convex hull for every record, how to process it for all all layer?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AS SELECT 1 as gid, ST_ConvexHULL(st_Collect(geom))::geometry(POLYGON,4326) as geom FROM xxx 
should do the job

Comment: Wow, thanks! I was almost there, didnt know about '1' after SELECT. I was putting column that exist in building table.